# How to show a string into foreach?

Tags: php, api, object

i'm extracting some datas of an api, but when i use foreach to show the info that i need, i have this error:
**Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given**

The info that i need is:

[image]

I know that into this object i have a string, but what i need do to extract this?

There is my code:

```
foreach($messageRecords->messageData as $messageData){
                    //print_r($messageData);
                    foreach($messageData->text as $text){
                        print_r($text);
                    }
                }
```

Can anyone help me plz?
Tks.

Answer (score 0):

`$messageData->text` is a string u cant use a string in a foreach loop. if u want to print that text I guess u don't need the second loop. I don't know what exactly is your project is but try using `var_dump()` in the loop for variables u have to find out what should u do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function for this.
If you want to iterate through lines in your string, try this one:

```
<?php
foreach($messageRecords->messageData as $messageData){                     
    foreach(explode('\r\n', $messageData->text) as $text) {
       echo $text;
    }
}
```

Here '\r\n' is a line separator.